# Problem sending notifications to iOS flutter app using FCM

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications to a flutter app using Firebase cloud messaging. Unfortunately, I'm having problems receiving the notifications on my iOS device. I'm testing it on a physical iPhone.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
import FirebaseMessaging
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting FCM token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let token = token {
                print("FCM token: \(token)")
            }
        }
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("****")
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
    ) {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    func messaging(
        _ messaging: Messaging,
        didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?
    ) {
        guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else {
            return
        }
        print("FCM token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
}
```

I have been able to send notifications to android devices in the same app using FCM. So I don't think it's a problem with my dart code. But here are some snippets from my main file just in case.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
```

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  NotificationSettings settings = await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    }
  });

  StoreConfig(
    store: Store.appleStore,
    apiKey: appleApiKey,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: make sure you have turn on push notifications in apple developer account for your provisioning profile and also added p12 in your firebase